# How can I extend a local class in a function?

Tags: python, subclass

Here is the structure i'm dealing with

```
class myclass():
    def function(self):
        class localclass():
            params = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
        return localclass
```

I want to add parameters in class localclass, but not directly in class 'myclass' definition.
So I want to call/override function and/or class localclass to add params with the method

`params.update({'d': 4, 'e': 5})`

How do i do that?

THanks.

Comment: Think of what you would do if the class were not "local".  Then do exactly the same thing to the object returned by the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a decorator:

```
def update(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        cls = func(*args)
        cls.params.update({'d': 4, 'e': 5})
        return cls
    return wrapper        

class myclass(object):
    @update
    def function(self):
        class localclass(object):
            params = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
        return localclass
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> a = myclass()
>>> a.function().params
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: Actually I did't want to write in the class file, so I used this instead: `super().func(*args)` and `cls.params.update()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like the following, no need to modify any of your current code:

```
>>> obj = myclass()
>>> cls = obj.function()
>>> cls.params.update({'d': 4, 'e': 5})
>>> cls.params
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: That's the idea yes. But my master class is actually a Django Admin class, so i don't want to create a new instance. I want to add parameters when the function is read.